# Can I prioritize IPv6 traffic over IPv4 traffic on Linux?

Tags: linux, ipv6, ipv4

Is there a way I can give traffic over IPv6 a higher priority than traffic over IPv4?

Purpose is 2-fold: Promote IPv6, and be able to connect even when my server is swamped by IPv4 users.

Comment: You almost certainly can't prioritize inbound traffic, unless you control the device that decides what inbound traffic to put on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `tc`, but it [appears](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/) that you can at least limit traffic based on specific markers set via `iptables`. If that works, you can then just limit IPv4 traffic to, say, 95% of your interface’s bandwidth by setting the appropriate marker in iptables, but not in ip6tables.

Further reading of the associated manpages probably would reveal more information :)

Regarding [David Schwartz’](https://superuser.com/questions/483774/can-i-prioritize-ipv6-traffic-over-ipv4-traffic-on-linux#comment573911_483774) remark, I would like to point out that, provided traffic is TCP-based, appropriate delaying of TCP ACK packages should do the trick with regard to inbound traffic – although, certainly, not perfectly so.